# Is it possible to find the datatype of a variable in C?

Tags: c

I know it is very clearly mentioned during input operation but want to know . Like in Python3.6 we have "type()" function. Just curious about it.

Comment: C doesn't have [type introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection).

Comment: Although C does not have type introspection, there is a GNU C extension called [`typeof`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html).

Comment: There is the `_Generic` macro added in C11, which does value selection based on type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something with [_Generic()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) from C11 as long as you know the types you care about ahead of time:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define Type(x) _Generic((x),                   \
                         int: "int",            \
                         short: "short",        \
                         long: "long",          \
                         char: "char",          \
                         float: "float",        \
                         double: "double",      \
                         default: "unknown"     \
                         )

int main(void) {
  int i;
  short s;
  long lng;
  long long llng;
  char c;
  float f;
  double d;
  printf("%s\n", Type(i));
  printf("%s\n", Type(s));
  printf("%s\n", Type(lng));
  printf("%s\n", Type(llng));
  printf("%s\n", Type(c));
  printf("%s\n", Type(f));
  printf("%s\n", Type(d));
}
```

when compiled and run produces:

```
int
short
long
unknown
char
float
double
```

Comment: clever use of _Generic()!

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing of the sorts of `type()` is available in C. In Python the variables do not have types. They all are references - or pointers if you will - to the actual objects. This is unlike in C where variables too *are* objects themselves

The type of the objects is often the type of the *lvalue* used to access the memory. All tricks given in the answers here only find the type compile-time type i.e. the type of the lvalue or value of expression - all that is compile-type information - the compiler, while processing the file, can find out what those types are since they were declared there, i.e. they can find out the type of the variable.

But that is *not* what the Python `type` function does: `type` can find out the *type identity* of the pointed-to object:

```
def foo(i):
    if type(i) is int:
        ...
```

In here it is not the type of `i` that is being compared against `int` but the type of that object that is currently bound to that name `i`.

In C if you cast a pointer to object to `void *`, there's nothing to recover that information from. For example:

```
void do_something(void *p) {
    // ???
}

...

    int *a = malloc(sizeof int);
    *a = 42;
    void *p = a;
    do_something(p);
```

the `p` points to an object of (effective) type `int` with current value `42`, but it is of type `void *`. There is absolutely no generic mechanism in C for `do_something` to find out, given `p`, that it points to an object of type `int`. It just needs to be *known*.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to create your own variables manager through the precompiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR1(x)  #x
#define STR(x)  STR1(x)
#define variable(x,name) x var_##name; char* type_##name = STR(x)

int main() { 
    variable(float, testF);
    variable(int, testI);
}
```

See [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0CMQrODD3YMvYVWf)

Answer (score 0):

Python *variables* don't have types. Python *values* have types. Therefore it is sometines necessary to use `type()`: the same variable can hold values of different types, and the programmer doesn't necessarily know which type is currently being held.

```
p = foo() 
print (type(p)) # could be any type
p = bar() # the type can change
p = baz() # and again
```

C variables have types. They are statically known and explicitly declared by the programmer. The type of the value is the type of the variable. Therefore something like `type()` would be redundant. For a given variable, the tyoe is always the same. It is always possible to look at the declaration. With an IDE, this can be done in one click, no matter where the declaration is.

```
int p = foo(); // the type of p is int
p = bar(); // the type of p is int
p = baz(); // guess what, still int
```

There is more to this subject, e.g. macros, generics, void pointers, casts, dynamically allocated objects and more. These are all somewhat advanced topics though. One should unserstand the basics first.